# Постоянное движение вверх css

Tags: css, css-animation

Почему картинка доход до верха блока и опускается вниз? нужно чтобы постоянно вверх плыла как зацикленная

```
.clouds_one {
    background: url("../img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 7%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    -webkit-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
    /*0% {
        left: 0
    }
    100% {
        left: -200%
    }*/
        0%{
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что по умолчанию:

```
animation-direction: normal
```

Что значит постоянно плыла вверх?В любом случае элемент достигнет края,либо увеличить время,либо зациклить сверху с небольшими смещениями то вверх,то вниз.

Comment: animation-direction тогда убрать вообще?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы вниз не опускалось, как-то зациклить

Comment: У вас и так зациклено,чтобы сохранить состояние,свойство animation-fill-mode.

Comment: -webkit-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 animation-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;

Answer (score 0):

```
так? все ровно опускается вниз

-webkit-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cloud_one 70s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-direction: reverse;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
```